# Unable to map assertionSubjectName when handling SAML2 response

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I have created a custom TechnicalProfile using the SAML2 protocol and I use this profile in a User-Journey to log in to a 3rd party identity provider. My SAML AuthRequest works well and I receive a valid response.

This response contains a "Subject" element as shown below.

```
    <saml:Subject>
    <saml:NameID NameQualifier="REMOVED" 
    Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:persistent">REMOVED</saml:NameID>
    <saml:SubjectConfirmation Method="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:cm:bearer">
        <saml:SubjectConfirmationData NotOnOrAfter="2018-11-29T18:02:53Z" Recipient="REMOVED" InResponseTo="_d09b9112-adea-49f2-809f-8c5fcbaa6261" />
    </saml:SubjectConfirmation>
</saml:Subject>
```

According to documentation found here: [Active Directory B2C Advanced Policies - Features 6](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-advanced-policies/blob/master/Documentation/Features%20part%206.md)
and [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52670606/how-do-i-read-the-nameid-element-as-a-claim-in-a-b2c-technicalprofile-for-a-saml), I should be able access the value of the NameID element in my OutputClaims mapping by using a Partner Claim Type of "assertionSubjectName". I have done this as shown below:

```
 <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" PartnerClaimType="firstName"/>
      <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname" PartnerClaimType="lastName"/>
      <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="dob" PartnerClaimType="dateOfBirth"/>
      <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="emailAddress"/>
      <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" DefaultValue="socialIdpAuthentication"/>
      <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="identityProvider" DefaultValue="REMOVED" />
      <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="socialIdpUserId" PartnerClaimType="assertionSubjectName" />
```

All of the claims other than "socialIdpUserId" map correctly as they are found in the "AttributeStatement" element of the SAML Response, but the "socialIdpUserId" claim is not mapped. In fact - when tracing the User Journey via ApplicationInsights, the messaging from that step of the journey clearly indicates that the step is mapping those other claims, but the "socialIdpUserId" claim is not mentioned at all.

My question is this - has anyone actually seen the use of the "**assertionSubjectName**" operate successfully? Or am I reviewing out of date documentation and is there a "better" way to achieve the same end result that I am not currently aware of?

Comment: Found the reason why the "assertionSubjectName" did not work. There seems to be an undocumented behavior where a "NameQualifier" attribute on the NameID element will prevent Azure from extracting the NameID from the SAML Response. 

e.g. this works:
`<Subject>
            <NameID>foo</NameID>`

this doesn't:
`<Subject>
            <NameID NameQualifier="[some qualifier]">foo</NameID>`

That being said - this behavior seems less than desirable. I have reached out to MSFT for support to find out if this is WAD.
@Thomas - this may cause the issue you mentioned on the linked ticket.